# Phonegap: problemas ao criar buil android

Tags: apache-cordova, phonegap-buillder

Estou iniciando os trabalhos no Phonegap e não tenho conseguido fazer a build de meu projeto. Recebo os seguintes erros (conforme imagem abaixo):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu SDK está com os seguintes pacotes instalados:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei diversas opções, mas nada resolveu meu problema. Onde está meu erro?

Comment: A aplicação está com o target do Android API 22. E diz que não o tens instalado. No sdk manager, mais abaixo tens lá API 22, verifica se o tens instalado.

Comment: tenho a API 22 instalada sim (Android 5.1.1) e mesmo assim o problema persiste. Não sei mais o que fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Caso tenha instalado a API a partir do Android Studio, abra o gerenciador de pacotes a partir do terminal e confira novamente a instalação.
Tive um problema parecido, onde, abrindo o gerenciador pelo Android Studio aparecia como instalado e quando abri pelo terminal, apareceu como não instalado.